# Subnets in kubernetes

Tags: azure, networking, kubernetes, azure-service-fabric, azure-aks

I'm still experimenting with migrating my service fabric application to kubernetes. In service fabric I have two node types (effectively subnets), and for each service I configure which subnet it will be deployed to. I cannot see an equivalent option in the kubernetes yml file. Is this possible in kubernetes?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using multiple subnets? For what reason do you want to use multiple subnets?

Comment: I want my backend services that access my SQL database in a different subnet to the front-end. This way I can limit access to the DB to backend subnet only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, they are not effectively subnets. They could all be in the same subnet. But with AKS you have node pools. similarly to Service Fabric those could be in different subnets (inside the same vnet*, afaik). Then you would use [nodeSelectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) to assign pods to nodes on the specific node pool.

Same principle would apply if you are creating kubernetes cluster yourself, you would need to label nodes and use nodeSelectors to target specific nodes for your deployments.

Comment: I might be missing something, but looking at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-multiple-node-pools, it says that "All node pools must reside in the same subnet.". This seems to suggest I can only have one subnet, or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: hm, I swear to god this was working even before multiple node pools existed, but this configuration (multiple subnets) is probably not supported yet. I'm quite sure it will work when you create it using an ARM Template, for example

Comment: Ha, thanks, I'll look at doing it with an ARM template then.

Comment: but it won't be supported, even if it works and it might not survive an upgrade

Comment: you would be better of with [aks-engine](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/master/docs/topics/clusterdefinitions.md#agentpoolprofiles). it would be supported to have multiple node pools with different subnets

Answer (score 1):

In Azure the AKS cluster can be deployed to a specific subnet. If you are looking for deployment level isolation, deploy the two node types to different namespaces in k8s cluster. That way the node types get isolation and can be reached using service name and namespace combination

Answer (score 1):

> I want my backend services that access my SQL database in a different subnet to the front-end. This way I can limit access to the DB to backend subnet only.

This is an older way to solve network security. A more modern way is called *Zero Trust Networking*, see e.g. [BeyondCorp at Google](https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp/) or the book [Zero Trust Networks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491962194).

### Limit who can access what

The Kubernetes way to limit what service can access what service is by using [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/).

> A network policy is a specification of how groups of pods are allowed to communicate with each other and other network endpoints.
>
> NetworkPolicy resources use labels to select pods and define rules which specify what traffic is allowed to the selected pods.

This is a more *software defined* way to limit access, than the older subnet-based. And the rules are more *declarative* using Kubernetes Labels instead of hard-to-understand IP-numbers.

This should be used in combination with *authentication*.

For inspiration, also read [We built network isolation for 1,500 services to make Monzo more secure](https://monzo.com/blog/we-built-network-isolation-for-1-500-services).

> In the Security team at Monzo, one of our goals is to move towards a completely zero trust platform. This means that in theory, we'd be able to run malicious code inside our platform with no risk – the code wouldn't be able to interact with anything dangerous without the security team granting special access.

### Istio Service Entry

In addition, if using Istio, you can limit access to external services by using [Istio Service Entry](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/). It is possible to use custom Network Policies for the same behavior as well, e.g. [Cilium](https://cilium.io/).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll read up on it. Some of the back end services are a bit resource intensive, presumably I'd still need to use the nodeSelector approach above to ensure these services are on different nodes with different VM sizes.

Comment: FYI, the link to "Zero Trust Networks" book is 404'd as of March 19, 2023.